# How to insert in a B* tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have a B* tree of degree `m=3` with `7` in the root and `1,2,3,4,5,6` in the left child and `8,9,10,11,12,13` in the right.
Now I want to insert `14`. What do I do? The 14 will cause an overflow in the right child. How do I resolve this? Do I only split the right child, and move `11` up to the root or do I have to do something with the left child too?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the order in which you inserted the nodes, you can use this website to recreate your tree and simulate what will happen when you insert 14 and it'll animate it for you. It's a nice visual representation of how B-trees work. https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BTree.html

Comment: Also, if you want help with implementation, you may want to post an attempt you made at the solution and make sure you accept the solution if the answer solved your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Unfortunately the link you shared is only for B trees.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I completely misread your post. I'll try to find a better resource for you. Or explain it if I have the time.

Comment: I would appreciate that very much!